# Global Symbol Registry and cross realm symbols

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to understand the difference between Symbol() and Symbol.for() in regard to cross realm.

I have read this article:http://2ality.com/2014/12/es6-symbols.html where it is said that:

> Symbols have individual identities and thus don’t travel across realms as smoothly as other primitive values. That is a problem for symbols such as Symbol.iterator that should work across realms: If an object is iterable in one realm, it should be iterable in others, too. If a cross-realm symbol is provided by the JavaScript engine, the engine can make sure that the same value is used in each realm. For libraries, however, we need extra support, which comes in the form of the global symbol registry: This registry is global to all realms and maps strings to symbols. For each symbol, libraries need to come up with a string that is as unique as possible. To create the symbol, they don’t use Symbol(), they ask the registry for the symbol that the string is mapped to. If the registry already has an entry for the string, the associated symbol is returned. Otherwise, entry and symbol are created first.

Frankly, I don't know what does it mean that a symbol is accessable in one realm and not accessable in other. I have tried this piece of code:

```
  <iframe srcdoc="<script>var sym = Symbol(); var obj = {}; obj[sym] = 123;</script>">
  </iframe>
  <script>
    const iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');
    const content = iframe.contentWindow;
    const value = content.obj[content.sym]
  </script>
```

When consol logging value, in a realm other than iframe, I'm getting 123. Shouldn't `sym` not live in my script? Doesn't above code prove that Symbols indeed travel across realms?

Comment: Best to use code blocks only for code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distinction here is that when you do

```
const value = content.obj[content.sym]
```

you are accessing the *cross-realm* object `content.obj` with the *cross-realm* symbol `content.sym`. The parent frame may access both cross-realm items. The problem is that the "same" Symbol cannot be used to access a property in a *different* realm.

If Symbol S from a child realm is used to access an object from the child realm, and that object has S on it, there's no problem, as your example demonstrates. The problem is when Symbol S from the child realm is used to access an object from the **parent realm*, and that parent realm object also has a `foo` Symbol property on it, the cross-realm property lookup may fail:

```
<iframe srcdoc="<script>var sym = Symbol('foo');</script>">
  </iframe>
<script>
  const obj = {};
  const sym = Symbol('foo');
  obj[sym] = 'value';

  const iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');
  const content = iframe.contentWindow;
  const value = obj[content.sym];
  console.log(value); // undefined
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/k4xh97ge/

Result: `value` is `undefined`, because the symbol for `foo` on one realm is not the same as the symbol for `foo` on another realm. The property lookup would only work if

(1) the symbol was from the global symbol registry, as the article describes, or

(2) the parent realm object used the symbol from the child realm (which is a very, very strange thing to see), for example:

```
<iframe srcdoc="<script>var sym = Symbol('foo');</script>">
  </iframe>
<script>
  const obj = {};
  const crossRealmSymbol = document.querySelector('iframe').contentWindow.sym;
  obj[crossRealmSymbol] = 'value';
  console.log(obj[crossRealmSymbol]);
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/k4xh97ge/1/

Result: `value` is `'value'`

Comment: Oh! I get it now! Thanks a lot! Can you also explain me what whould happen if symbol: Symbol.iterator would not be a cross-realm symbol?

Comment: + why do you say "(...) property lookup MAY fail" ? Is it somehow browser dependent?

Comment: If `Symbol.iterator` wasn't cross-realm, it couldn't be iterated over in a different realm, because the Symbols would be different. The iterator protocol looks up the `Symbol.iterator` property on the object - if this `Symbol.iterator` was different for each realm, iterating would become much more cumbersome.

Comment: I should have phrased it: property lookup *will* fail unless the Symbols used are cross-realm, or unless (1) or (2) was done.

Comment: Don't get it. Being in realm B, we are taking object a from realm A. In realm A object a is iterable, so it has [Symbol.iterator] property on itself. What would have gone wrong if realm B would get object a from realm A and try to for-of on it assuming that Symbol.iterator is Symbol created by Symbol() and not Symobl.for()?

Comment: When you attempt to iterate an object, the interpreter looks up the `Symbol.iterator` property on the object. If you take an object from a child realm 
(or any other realm) and try to iterate it, *and* the `Symbol.iterator` in that child realm is the same (`===`) to the `Symbol.iterator` in the parent realm, there's no issue. But if each realm's `Symbol.iterator` is *different*, when trying to iterate over a cross origin object, the `obj[Symbol.iterator]` when in the context of the other realm would not exist - you'd need something like `obj[crossRealmSymbolIterator]` instead

Comment: Hmm... If I try to iterate on object from another real then shouldn't interpreter do something like objFromAnotherRealm[objFromAnotherRealm[Symbol.iterator]] under the hood? When looking at my very first example - this is exactly the same situation, right? You, on the other hand, say that when an interpreter tries to iterate over objFromAnotherRealm it will look for [Symbol.iterator] in its ream not another?

Comment: When in realm A, when iterating, it will always try to look up the `Symbol.iterator` property *in realm A*, even if the object being iterated over is in realm B. Luckily, `Symbol.iterator` is `===` across realms, so this doesn't cause a problem.

Comment: Ok, I assume you are right. But how do you know it? Where can I find such information?

Comment: The interpreter knows it can iterate over objects by looking to see if its own realm's `Symbol.iterator` property exists on the object. It doesn't consider any other realms, it just looks up the property. You can see how it works by plugging in `[...foo]` into [Babel](https://babeljs.io/repl/) - it just looks up `foo[Symbol.iterator]`. Figuring out that `foo` is cross-realm and then trying to find the `Symbol.iterator` of the other realm would be a whole lot more complicated.

Comment: Thanks for a deep explanation!